# configure dependency of a puppet module

Tags: puppet, configuration

I need to more finely tune the Apache vhost file being generated by the `example42/kibana` Puppet module. Is it possible in Puppet to 'reach through' the `example42/kibana` plugin and configure the `puppetlabs/apache` module directly?

For example, I need to modify the `apache::vhost.vhost_name` setting to `"*"` somehow (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#defined-type-apachevhost). Below is my current configuration for Kibana.

```
class { 'kibana':
    install_url => 'https://download.elasticsearch.org/kibana/kibana/kibana-3.1.0.zip',
    elasticsearch_url => "http://elastic.${::domain}:9200",

    webserver   => 'apache',
    virtualhost => "logs.${::domain}",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to [this vhost](https://github.com/example42/puppet-kibana/blob/master/manifests/dependency.pp#L25-27) that is declared inside the `kibana` module.

It is indeed possible to modify this resource. Note that the means to that basically form a monkey patch, so you should not rely on it too often. You do it using a resource override, similar to a virtual resource collector:

```
Apache::Vhost<| title == $kibana::virtualhost |> {
    vhost_name => '*'
}
```

As a cleaner alternative, you would need to enhance the module's interface (and ideally send your patch upstream).

Comment: yeah .. that does indeed look like a hack. Thanks for the answer. I don't like the idea of partially replicating an existing and perfectly decent module interface (the apache one) though, just for a little reuse. I'm going to investigate other frameworks.

Comment: Absolutely. It would likely be more sensible to add a switch that allows you to stop the Kibana module from managing the `vhost` at all, so that you can pull that into your own manifest if desired.

Comment: Agreed. I got lost in the puppet documentation getting frustrated trying to find an answer to this, expecting it to be a fairly common use case. I'll stick to keeping configuration shallow :|

Comment: ok, your snippet didn't work for me, but in keeping with what I said above, this does work for me: 
    apache::vhost { "logs.${::domain}":
      vhost_name => "*",
      port    => '80',
      docroot => '/opt/kibana-3.1.0',
    }

Comment: Did the override have no effect, or was there an error message? It bugs me that this didn't work :-)

Comment: iirc it didn't do anything if I put it after the kibana class declaration and gave me an error about an undefined 'kibana' resource if I put it before the kibana class declaration. It's not a big deal and I solved it by configuring apache directly.

Comment: its not finished yet, but here are the vagrant+puppet files I'm wokring on if you want to test it yourself: https://bitbucket.org/lskibinski/kibana-logstash-elasticsearch